# The type of field isn't supported by declared persistence strategy "OneToMany"

Tags: jpa, openjpa

We are new to JPA and trying to setup a very simple one to many relationship where a pojo called Message can have a list of integer group id's defined by a join table called `GROUP_ASSOC`. Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "APP"."MESSAGE" (
        "MESSAGE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
    );

ALTER TABLE "APP"."MESSAGE" ADD CONSTRAINT "MESSAGE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MESSAGE_ID");

CREATE TABLE "APP"."GROUP_ASSOC" (
        "GROUP_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "MESSAGE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL
    );

ALTER TABLE "APP"."GROUP_ASSOC" ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUP_ASSOC_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MESSAGE_ID", "GROUP_ID");

ALTER TABLE "APP"."GROUP_ASSOC" ADD CONSTRAINT "GROUP_ASSOC_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MESSAGE_ID")
    REFERENCES "APP"."MESSAGE" ("MESSAGE_ID");
```

Here is the pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int messageId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List groupIds;

    public int getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }
    public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }
    public List getGroupIds() {
        return groupIds;
    }
    public void setGroupIds(List groupIds) {
        this.groupIds = groupIds;
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong as there is no `@Column` mapping to `GROUP_ASSOC.GROUP_ID` for the groupIds property, but hopefully this illustrates what we are trying to do. When we run the following test code we get `<openjpa-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:907835 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: The type of field "pojo.Message.groupIds" isn't supported by declared persistence strategy "OneToMany". Please choose a different strategy.`

```
Message msg = new Message();
List groups = new ArrayList();
groups.add(101);
groups.add(102);
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDBWeb").createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(msg);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with JPA, you should think Object and relations between Objects and you should map your Object model, not `ids`, to your relational model (it is possible to map a `List` of basic values with [`@ElementCollection`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) in JPA 2.0 though but what I said just before still applies).

Here, (assuming this really is a **one-to-many** relation between `Message` and `GroupAssoc` and not a **many-to-many** relation between `Message` and `Group` entities) you should have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class Message implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    private Long messageId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)    
    private List<GroupAssoc> groupAssocs = new ArrayList<GroupAssoc>();

    public Long getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }
    public void setMessageId(Long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public List<GroupAssoc> getGroupAssocs() {
        return groupAssocs;
    }
    public void setGroupAssocs(List<GroupAssoc> groupAssocs) {
        this.groupAssocs = groupAssocs;
    }

    // equals() and hashCode()
}
```

And another entity for `GroupAssoc`.

PS: Your DDL really looks like a (M:N) relation between `MESSAGE` and `GROUP` (or I don't understand the PK constraint of `GROUP_ASSOC`) but you didn't show any FK constraint on `GROUP_ID` so I'm not 100% sure. But if that's the case, then you should use an `@ManyToMany` instead of `@OneToMany`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I should have mentioned that our application needs to display groupIds (in the UI) and that list of groupId's is what we ultimately need to query for by message. I think it is an M:N relationship because two massages may share the same groupIds.

Comment: My DDL is my best guess as to how to efficiently model this list of integers so there may be a problem with it (I'm a UI developer not a DBA). It seems cumbersome to create a separate `GroupAssoc` pojo especially if we have to create a third identity class (since it has a composite primary key) just to query for a list of groupIds for a given message.

Comment: @Robert You wouldn't have to create a third entity, JPA abstract the implementation at the database level. So you would get a List of `GroupAssoc` and iterate on the list to get each id.

Comment: So the `GroupAssoc` pojo doesn't need to have `@Id` or `@IdClass`?

Comment: @Robert Not easy to discuss in a 600 char box :) `GroupAssoc` does need to have a property annotated with `@Id`, I didn't say it doesn't. What I said is that you don't need a third entity for the "join table". JPA can map a `Message-*--*-Group` object model to the representation `Message-0--n-MessageGroup-m--0-Group` in database without the need for an entity for `MessageGroup`. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. I agree that this is not an easy discussion via comments, so I created a follow-up post where I've tried your suggestions as far as I understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501383/persisting-a-list-of-integers-with-jpa